# Is there a way to make a class behave like a tuple in numpy array indexing?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to create a kind of `Pos` **mutable** class that acts as a 2D point supporting arithmetic operations. But I would like this class to behave as a tuple when used in the specific case of numpy array indexing (to treat its values as coordinate inside a matrix).

Is there a way to make instances of this class to behave like a this (or some kind of magic method similar to `__index__` before it is passed to indexing) ?

BTW, I would also be happy if a ndarray could be used as this Point class without having to manually call a method :

```
from numpy import array
A = np.array(list(range(12)))).reshape(3,4)
```

```
>>> A
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> A[array([1,2])]
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Wanted :

```
>>> A[Pos(1,2)]
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could subclass `tuple` and use that? Real mutability like with lists is hard, but a simple workaround would be to implement a `set` function and instead of just doing `p[0] = 2` you do `p = p.set(0, 2)`:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import numpy as np


class Pos(tuple):
    def set(self, key: int, value: int) -> Pos:
        self_items = list(self)
        self_items[key] = value
        return Pos(self_items)


a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
t = Pos([0, 1])
print(a[t])  # 2
t = t.set(0, 1)
print(a[t])  # 4
```

Comment: I forgot to tell it should be mutable...